# Having trouble with invalid argument supplied for foreach?

Tags: php

Please someone help I am very new to PHP, so bear with me.

Link to the site using the code below;

I am basically copying code from a site (http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/), and trying to implement into my own site project.

Here is the problem code....

```
  <ul id="headlines">

<?php foreach ( $results['articles'] as $article ) { ?>

    <li>
      <h2>
        <span class="pubDate"><?php echo date('j F', $article->publicationDate)?></span>
        <a href=".?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?php echo $article->id?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->title )?></a>
      </h2>
      <p class="summary"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->summary )?></p>
    </li>

<?php } ?>

  </ul>

  <p><a href="./?action=archive">Article Archive</a></p>
```

Here is my error message:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/news/homepage.php on line 3

Comment: Can you past the foreach code, and the code where the array is being initialized?

Comment: Well, does `$results['articles']` exist and if yes, what is its value? If you are new to PHP, you probably want to read the [`foreach` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). In general, just copy and pasting code without understanding it is not particularly promising. If you are new, you should first learn the language and then use it.

Comment: So, where have you used the foreach loop? Please give that code.. It's that snippet that matters.

Comment: `$results['articles']` is probably null (or at the very least, it is not a collection). Show the code where you set it.

Comment: The problem is that `$results['articles']` is not an array or iterable object. How did you assign a value to `$results['articles']` - please show the code.

Answer (score 1):

`$results['articles']` is not an array. You should set it either to an empty array or skip the `foreach` loop when it is not an array - null, string, number etc.

```
<ul id="headlines">

<?php if (!$results['articles']) $results['articles'] = array(); ?>
<?php foreach ( $results['articles'] as $article ) { ?>

    <li>
      <h2>
        <span class="pubDate"><?php echo date('j F', $article->publicationDate)?></span>
        <a href=".?action=viewArticle&amp;articleId=<?php echo $article->id?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->title )?></a>
      </h2>
      <p class="summary"><?php echo htmlspecialchars( $article->summary )?></p>
    </li>

<?php } ?>

  </ul>

  <p><a href="./?action=archive">Article Archive</a></p>
```

This is just a quick-fix. But when you've got an empty `$results['articles']` this probably means you have an error in your code, which fills that array or you've got no articles matching your criteria =)

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" code has nothing to do with the problem.

$results['articles'] is not an array - that's all. you have to verify the code where $results['articles'] is assigned to find what's the problem is.

most likely you have no data in your database or something like that.